# Need help in writing SOSL query

Tags: apex, sosl

I have three objects:

- `ccrz__E_Order__c`
- `ccrz__E_OrderItem__c`
- `CC_Account_Address`

Relation between these are as below.

I have this `ccrz__Order__c`(Master detail with `ccrz__E_Order__c`
  ) on `ccrz__E_OrderItem__c`.

I have this `ccrz__Account_Address__c`(Look up with `CC_Account_Address`
  ) on `ccrz__E_OrderItem__c`.

I want to create SOSL query which search through this object any populate result. I have mention the field name which i want to use in this SOSL.

```
ccrz__E_Order__c(Object name)---> ccrz__OrderId__c(Field name)

ccrz__E_Order__c(Object name)---> PONUmber__c(Field name)

ccrz__E_OrderItem__c(Object name)---->Product_Name(Field name)

CC_Account_Address(Object name)---->ship_to_address(Fieldname)

CC_Account_Address(Object name)---->status(Fieldname)
```

---

I did something like this but not sure what is the perfect way to do this

```
orderhistory = New List<ccrz__E_Order__c>();
            orderitem = New List<ccrz__E_OrderItem__c>();
            orderline = New List< CC_Account_Address >();
            if(searchStr.length() > 1){
            String searchStr1 = '*'+searchStr+'*';
            String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + searchStr1 + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING  ccrz__E_Order__c (ccrz__OrderId__c, PONUmber__c),ccrz__E_OrderItem__c(Product_Name), CC_Account_Address(ship_to_address, status)';
            List<List <sObject>> searchList = search.query(searchQuery);
            orderhistory = ((List<ccrz__E_Order__c>)searchList[0]);
            orderitem  = ((List<ccrz__E_OrderItem__c>)searchList[1]);
            orderline = ((List< CC_Account_Address >)searchList[2]);
```

Comment: whats exactly the issue you are facing?